# Convert List<T> to List<object>

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the generic class. I have something like this:

```
public abstract class IGroup<T> : IEnumerable where T : class {

    protected List<T> groupMembers;
    protected List<IGameAction> groupIGameActionList;

    public IGroup() {
        groupMembers = new List<T>();

        groupIGameActionList = new List<IGameAction>();
        //groupIGameActionList.Add(new DieGameAction(groupMembers));
    }
}
```

And second class:

```
class DieGameAction : IGameAction {

    List<object> gameObjectList;

    public DieGameAction(List<object> objectList) {
        gameObjectList = objectList; 
    }
}
```

I don't know how to cast or convert `groupMembers` in commented line. This doesn't work because it can not be converted (`List<T>` to `List<object>`). So how can I do it?

Comment: How will you use `gameObjectList`? Is there a good reason for it not to be a `List<IGameAction>` ?

Comment: So if `DieGameAction` writes: `objectList.Add("hello")` what should happen?  You've now added a string to a list of `IGameAction` objects!!!

Comment: Perhaps `DieGameAction` should be generic and have a `List<T>` rather than a `List<object>`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
groupMembers.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

But that doesn't look a good thing to do. You are creating a new empty list that will not be related to the original anymore.

The way you're gonna be using these classes will tell if that would be a good idea.
If you're planning to have both lists updated by adding items to a single class, it will not fit. Then maybe your `DieGameAction` should be generic as well: `DieGameAction<T>`.
Then you could give the original list without casting.

But, there's another danger: if you set a new list to the IGroup, it will not be reflected to DieGameAction.

So, it all depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Beware that this will copy the list.

Comment: @SLaks What's the problem with that?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance We can't know; it depends on how the list is used.  A copy may be fine, it might not be.  If it is, then it probably means the parameter *should* have just been an `IEnumerable` instead so it could have covariance.

Comment: As you pointed out though, that doesn't appear to be the case here.  He's passing in an empty list, so I imagine he's relying on a shared reference to the list.

Comment: I need original reference on the list.

Comment: @wolen Then it's not possible as it stands, you'll need to go into more detail about what you're really trying to do so that someone could help you fundamentally re-disign this whole process to something that *is* possible.

Comment: I know T is IGameObject so I can do `public abstract class IGroup<T> : IEnumerable where T : class, IGameObject`. But it doesn't help.

Comment: If T is `ALWAYS` an `IGameObject`, forget about generics and simply use a `List<IGameObject>` instead of a `List<T>`

Comment: And probably your `DieGameAction` would be using only `List<IGameObject>` as well.

Comment: So I can try to descripe my problem. I have `IGroup` object as container for IGameObject (it is IMoveble...IStatic...IBullet...etc) `IGroup` has functions like Add or Remove so groupMembers are changed during a game. IGameAction is method called from GUI (OnMouseClicked) and this gameAction kill all objects in `IGroup`

Comment: So List<IGameObject> will be fine. I am re-designing project so IGameObject is new ancestor and I did not realize it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be fine if the IGroup had a `KillAll` method? That would avoid duplicating the references to the list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30593/discussion-between-wolen-and-daniel)

Comment: I would, but my server blocks the chat for me. (Company rules)

Comment: Never mind. I solved it. I used some generic and inheritance and this problem is solved. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

I just faced the same problem which led me here. The solution that worked for me was to cast into IEnumerable of Object instead of List of Object

```
(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>)groupMembers;
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question but by declaring your variable as `IList` instead of `List<object>`, you can assign a list (or array) of any type to the variable and simply cast it to `IList<Whatever>` later (of course it's going to throw an exception if you cast it to a wrong type). I have found this more efficient than having to do `.Cast<object>()` every time you want to assign something to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to focus only on providing a solution.
You can make DieGameAction use IList < object > instead:

```
class DieGameAction : IGameAction {

    IList<object> gameObjectList;

    public DieGameAction(IList<object> objectList) {
        gameObjectList = objectList; 
    }
}
```

Then you can provide an IList < object > implementation which adapts any IList < T >.

```
public abstract class IGroup<T> : IEnumerable where T : class {

    protected List<T> groupMembers;
    protected List<IGameAction> groupIGameActionList;

    public IGroup() {
        groupMembers = new List<T>();

        groupIGameActionList = new List<IGameAction>();
        groupIGameActionList.Add(new DieGameAction(new ObjectListAdapter<T>(groupMembers)));
    }
}
```

I'm going to try and provide one of the many possible solutions using as base the System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection < T > which can also wrap an IList < T >:

```
public class ObjectListAdapter<T> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>, IList<object>
{
    public ObjectListAdapter(IList<T> wrappedList)
        : base(wrappedList)
    {
    }

    public int IndexOf(object item)
    {
        return base.IndexOf((T)item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, object item)
    {
        base.Insert(index, (T)item);
    }

    public new object this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return base[index];
        }
        set
        {
            base[index] = (T)value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(object item)
    {
        base.Add((T)item);
    }

    public bool Contains(object item)
    {
        return base.Contains((T)item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(object[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        this.Cast<object>().ToArray().CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(object item)
    {
        return base.Remove((T)item);
    }

    public new IEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Cast<object>().GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The list changes will throw a type casting exception upon trying to use an unsupported object, the way I programmed it over here, but you can also handle that as you like.

Now, for IList < object > you could also try using IList instead which is also implemented by List < T > so you'll basically have to do nothing more to get this working.

Note that the important thing is that the list will appear the same at both places used since they will basically be using the same underlying List object.

Let me know if this answers your question, by marking it as an answer, or not to refrain :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue today but i called the `LINQ .ToArray()` on it directly and it works fine. that should be `shorter` than `casting`.
 so you could say

```
groupMembers.ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me like this:

```
List<myclass> listMyclass = new List<myclass>();
var listObject = listMyclass.ToList<object>();
```