# How do I make a method that accepts a list of any type

Tags: c#, .net, list, types

How do I make a method that accepts a list of any type? Doing `List<object>` gives me the error

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<VirusThing.Person>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List' [Virus thing]

What do I need to change to make the following method work with any type of list?

```
public static void printList(List<object> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.Write(item);
    }
}
```

I saw that Java has something like `List<?>` that accepts any type of list.

Comment: @zaggler, unfortunately, no, I'm only showing an example of the problem I'm facing because it's much simpler to ask a question with a question that everyone understands than a question that only I can understand. If you want me to edit my current question to the question that I wanted to ask then sure I'll edit it.

Comment: S.a. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741739/convert-listt-to-listobject/29450289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is better to use generic

```
public static void printList<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
    }
```

but if you use a complex class, like Person,  you will have to override ToString

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Person: " + Name + " " + Age;
    }
}
```

or you can use more complicated code that is using reflections

```
public static void printList<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (item.GetType().IsPrimitive || item.GetType().Name=="String") Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        else printProperties(item);
    }
}
public static void printProperties<T>(T item)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" { property.Name}  : { property.GetValue(item, null).ToString()}");
    }
}
```

in this case,  all properties of instance will be printed, and you don't need to override ToString if you don' t need to show properties the special way.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the method generic like so

`public static void printList<T>(List<T> list)`

But this means you have to supply the type at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your method generic and add a constraint to just accept Types that derive from `List<>`

```
public static void printList<T>(T list)  where T: List<T>
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.Write(item);
    }
}
```

or use in this way :

```
  public static void printList<T>(List<T> list) {
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.Write(item);
    }
}
```